# Using the entity framework model to store textbox values

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am fairly new to ASP.NET and  I am trying to figure out how to use the entity framework model to data from a textbox field and store it in an existing field in a database which is available to the application .

I looked around on the internet and some solutions were to use a detailView but that would require me to recode the entire page and I would like to avoid that.

Can anyone provide any inputs on how to go about that ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Sounds like too broad question. Have you already tried any tutorial with Entity framework (doesn't have to be for asp.net application)? If yes you should know steps needed to do it. If not it's time to find some: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For an introduction to using EF with ASP.NET see the tutorials at http://asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials -- there are two series there for Web Forms and one for MVC.  Both of them have examples of using textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = new MyEntities();
var myObject = new myObjectType();
myObject.myValue = myTextBox.Text;
context.myObjectTypes.Add(myObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks @Kappsims and Ladislav

I  kind of figured it out that I would need to create a object to the connect to the database and map it the text area fields to the corrosponding rows but I am stuck at what to do next beyond that stage

Comment: The code currently is :
rotected void Onbutton_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = new PrepLicensingSolution2010.DAL.LicensingOrgInfo();
            obj.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            obj.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            obj.EmailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text;
            obj.PersonTitle = txtTitle.Text;
           
            
        }

Comment: you have to declare your context, map the data, and then add the object to your context, and call SaveChanges().

Comment: Thanks ,sorry for getting back so late